# Handle Core Data Fetching Object Which No Longer Exists

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

**Background Info:**

I have an application that accesses a user's email account and fetches account data: emails, folders etc.  This process includes several steps, the last of which is to save or update newly fetched information to core data. The whole process from start to finish may take a couple of seconds.

**Here is the problem:**

1. User opens application, fetching of new or updated account data process begins.
2. User decides to delete the current account for which fetching is occurring.
3. A call is sent to cancel any open fetch requests for the current account, however, the fetch requests are completed and core data is now trying to save the new data.
4. While trying to access "existing" core data objects in order to update them, the objects are deleted and a crash occurs.

Specifically, the error I get looks like:

```
CoreData: annotation: logically false fetch request <NSFetchRequest: 0x13ce1430> (entity:     Thread; predicate: (threadId == 1457719230395529203 AND folder == <Folder: 0xc1994c0> (entity: Folder; id: 0xc2ccb20 <x-coredata://A0837E88-30EB-46E8-A9BC-D6699EC7F160/Folder/p10> ; data: <fault>)); sortDescriptors: ((null)); type: NSManagedObjectResultType; ) short circuits.
```

And the crash is occurring on a line where core data is attempting to fetch an object that no longer exists.

Being new to core data, I am wondering if there is a general strategy for handling such a circumstance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can separate this kind of logical work on the data model so that it each major operation completes before the next one is started by using operations on a queue.

In this specific case, it just sounds like the cancellation of the current request isn't being handled correctly. You should be able to stop pending operations once the activity has been cancelled. You may need to add a flag and check if the activity is cancelled after each asynchronous callback and before saving modifications.